# Old 1990's point and click game, first person adventure, odd story

Tags: story-identification, video-games

A long time ago I remember playing a fantasy PC game where an old French adventurer is interviewed by a reporter about an expedition he went as a young man. The Reporter then tries to pick up the expedition where he left off.

I used to have a book that had all the flora and fauna of that game (looked pretty cool and plausible in terms of biology). I remember it being based off of a French Comic Strip and a Movie in the 80's

I don't remember much, it had planes powered by floppy disks, villages turned into dictatorships, suicide, assassinations, Giant eggs and white birds with no feet, weird animals and being very difficult to complete at the age of 7.

I know it's not much to go on but that is all I remember, it's been gnawing at me for over 15 years and I still remember the game, I just don't know the name.

Comment: I would have thought this was a fit for Gaming Stack Exchange, but their criteria for the [Game Identification tag](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) are quite strict

Comment: I tried to ask them the same question yesterday but since I don't have any pictures (I don't have the book anymore either) the question was closed.

Comment: Can you remember when the game was released, or who published it?

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - yeah, if you've seen some of the game-id questions that come in, you'd see why. Most text descriptions fit a dozen or more similar titles, and that's if the user was detailed, ranging into the hundreds if they weren't.  I'm glad this was an adventure game, which is probably one of the only genres with enough plot focus to distinguish them so we can be helpful.

Comment: @Radhil: I haven't been a gamer for years, so don't hang out there, I'm not bashing your reasons dude :)

Comment: This would be a fit for [retrocomputing.se]; we already have one question like it. However, this game was based on another form of story so might be (read: has been) answered better here.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sounds like [*Amerzone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerzone) (1999) by Benoît Sokal:

> Like the comic, the game tells the story of a French explorer, Alexandre Valembois, who goes on an expedition to the mysterious South American country of Amerzone. There, he discovers many fantastical animals including a species of magical White Birds, who require human intervention for their survival. These become threatened when a friend of Valembois turns Amerzone into a brutal dictatorship, and Valembois endeavors to rescue the endangered species. The game adds a journalist as the player character, who continues Valembois's quest as the man nears death.

I think I never played it myself, but the later games from Sokal were great and I loved them.

There was an [Android re-release](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microids.amerzone&hl=en).

Comment: "It's been gnawing at me for 15 years" "Here, let me answer it in an hour, and oh BTW there's a modern remake."  Uh, *nice*.

Comment: I didn't know this was from a comic...

Comment: The credit for the Android remake link goes to FuzzyBoots who enhanced my answer, I didn't know that. The strange story just reminded my of Sokal games and it was pure luck that I found that Amerzone had white birds in it :D. But glad I could help (also gave me tons of rep and a new batch)